# Android replaceContentView has a max view usable?

Tags: android, android-intent, view, replace

I'm using this code (from a class with a textarea and some button, very easy):

```
final Intent i1=new Intent(getBaseContext(),Domanda9.class);
replaceContentView("Calledw", i1);
```

and this:

```
public void replaceContentView(String id, Intent newIntent){
    getLocalActivityManager().destroyActivity("Called", true);
    View view = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(id,newIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)) .getDecorView(); 
    this.setContentView(view);
}
```

to change the view in my "survey app", but i notice that after the 9th change, the app crash with this logcat:
https://dl.dropbox.com/u/16047047/log.txt
maybe there's a limit? how can i solve this? there's a way to empty something?

Comment: .. Why are you trying to set the content view like this? Why not just start a new activity as normal? or replace the contentView with a proper layout file setContentView(R.layout.new_layout); ?

Comment: Gotcha. Makes sense now. Posted an answer that should solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are destroying your previous activity before adding the new one.. Ex.

```
getLocalActivityManager().destroyActivity("Calledw", true);
```

You are running your older activities while still adding new ones which will eventually lead to memory issues

Just make sure you pass in the proper ID for the activity you want to destroy

Comment: It is always on the 9th activity you add ? Have you tried launching the 9th activity that's crashing separate to make sure its not a problem with the activity itself. Or perhaps add the 9th activity first to eliminate it as the problem

Comment: can you see if i have written it well? I've edited the first post

Comment: You have the ID wrong in the destroy call.. You are adding "Calledw" and destroying "Called" (Note the missing "w") Change your destroy call so it destroys "Calledw"

Comment: If you always add/remove the same ID just change the destroy call to getLocalActivityManager().destroyActivity(id, true);  

This way it removes the ID you pass into your replaceContentView method

Comment: no it was ok. the id is Called.
However, there's no technique that work.
So i have adopted another way using frames

Comment: Interesting. Not sure why that wouldn't work. Sorry I couldn't help. However, it's maybe a good thing since the TabActivity is deprecated and Fragment should be used instead